# Why is the Firebase authentication method call patttern used?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Why do the Firebase authentication patterns use

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
auth.<signin type>.addOnCompleteListener
```

Instead of adding the onCompleteListener to the auth object before making the authentication attempt?  Isn't there a race condition if one does not use:

```
auth.addOnCompleteListener(...)
auth.<signon attempt>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start a sign-in flow, it returns a task. That task completes when the auth flow completes (either successfully or with an error). It's a promise-like API, which means that you can add the completion listener late and it will still be invoked.

I prefer using an `AuthStateListener` myself though:

```
auth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        setCurrentUser(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser());
    }
});
```

The `onAuthStateChanged()` method will be called immediate with the current auth state and then whenever the auth state changes. This removes any fear for race conditions from my mind and makes my code very "reactive".

I think we internally called these time-varying values, but am not sure if that's also the more general term for them.

Comment: I am concerned about using a proper model when one might be performing authentication with multiple "authentication" types. One use case would be: 1) logon anonymously; 2) if user wants/needs to access more advanced capability, loging using new method (e.g. eMail, password) or google authentication or ... 3) link the authetication types

I would want to ensure that the "onComplete" listener for the anonymous call does not get the completion of the "email, password" authentication (so attache listener first), but I dont whaat the "email, password" listener to get anonymous call ..(ck done?)