# SharedPreferences to Firebase Authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, sharedpreferences

I use Firebase Authentication to take care of the Sign-In process in my app.

I recently added the option to 'Remember me" by using `SharedPreferences`.

When I use `SharedPreferences` as follows:

```
if (Cb_RememberMe.isChecked()){
    getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .putString(PREF_USERNAME, email)
            .putString(PREF_PASSWORD, password)
            .apply();
}
```

Then all it does is saving the `email` and `password` as is to the `SharedPreferences` .xml file.

I would like to encrypt that data before I save it to my `SharedPreferences`.

My question is how do I then de-encrypt that information in my `SharedPreferences` so when I read it back to the login screen, I won't have a problem in my Firebase Authentication.

If it is by using a key, then how does it offers a secure method if the key itself is shared also in the SharedPreference?

I saw there is something called JetPack however couldn't find any java guide.

Comment: What if the phone has been restarted? or if someone if not using smartlock

Comment: Firebase Authentication already persists the user's authentication state across app restarts. I'd highly recommend using an `onAuthStateChanged` listener to restore that state, instead of implementing your own mechanism. For an example of this, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424625/why-is-the-firebase-authentication-method-call-patttern-used/37425029#37425029

Comment: Firebase Authentication is usually pretty good about restoring the auth state. Give the code in my answer to the question I linked a try, and see how it behaves under the circumstances you're interested in.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry, I cant understand how I can use this in order to save the email/password if the phone has restarted.

Comment: It doesn't same email/password (that would've been an answer ), but it removes the need to save them at all. Firebase takes care of that, so I'd recommend using that instead of trying to save them yourself.

Comment: Can you please explain more? Cant find any data on it. Does it mean that I need to write this code in any activity for the case it restart in any of them?

Comment: I have a feeling this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where I'd much rather help you with the X; in this case: restoring user authentication state with Firebase. Your code shows nothing on how you use Firebase Authentication, nor what about that doesn't work. If you add those in your question, we might be able to help further.